# paste special values in vba

Tags: excel, xlsm, vba

I am working on a small project which requires me to copy and paste certain columns if I detect "true" in the row. I am trying to paste these selected columns onto a different sheet and I want to paste only their values not the formulas.

This is what I have so far and I am getting an error with the paste special feature. Please help.

```
' CopyIfTrue()
Dim Col As Range, Cell As Excel.Range, RowCount As Integer
Dim nysheet As Worksheet
Set nysheet = Sheets.Add()
nysheet.Name = "T1"

Sheets("FemImplant").Select
RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set Col = Range("I2:I" & RowCount) 'Substitute with the range which includes your True/False values
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For Each Cell In Col      
     If Cell.Value = "True" Then                  
        Cell.Copy
        Sheets("T1").Select 'Substitute with your sheet
        Range("b" & i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Get sibling cell

        Sheets("FemImplant").Select
        Dim thisRow As Integer
        thisRow = Cell.Row
        Dim siblingCell As Range
        Set siblingCell = Cells(thisRow, 2)
        siblingCell.Copy
        Sheets("T1").Select 'Substitute with your sheet
        Range("a" & i).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Sheets("FemImplant").Select
         i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What does "getting an error" mean? When you type the words "an error", the **very next thing** you should start typing is the error you're getting, complete with the **exact** error message with any memory addresses. We can't see your screen from where we sit, and giving the error information makes it much easier to help you get an answer. "getting an error" without details is absolutely useless to people not sitting at your desk. :-) Please edit your question and provide those details so we can help you solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user1452091: I would recommend using autofilter instead of looping through each row. That would be much faster ")

Answer (score 10):

PasteSpecial must be Range.PasteSpecial not ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial. They are different things and ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial does not know any parameter "Paste".

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a" & i).PasteSpecial Paste = xlPasteValues
```

Comment: In my case, I used the following syntax... ActiveSheet.Range("a" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) I hope this helps you too! Thank you. Peace!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer, i As Long
    Dim nysheet As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("T1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set nysheet = Sheets.Add()
    nysheet.Name = "T1"

    With Sheets("FemImplant")
        RowCount = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        Set rRange = .Range("I2:I" & RowCount)

        With rRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="True"

            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            nysheet.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            .Offset(1, -7).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            nysheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy/paste can be shortened considerably...

```
' CopyIfTrue()
Dim Col As Range, Cell As Excel.Range, RowCount As Integer
Dim nysheet As Worksheet, shtFI As Worksheet

Set shtFI = Sheets("FemImplant")
Set nysheet = Sheets.Add()
nysheet.Name = "T1"

RowCount = shtFI.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set Col = shtFI.Range("I2:I" & RowCount)

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For Each Cell In Col.Cells
     If Cell.Value = "True" Then
        Cell.Copy nysheet.Range("B" & i)
        nysheet.Range("A" & i).Value = _
                       shtFI.Cells(Cell.Row, 2).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you provided is much faster than earlier. 
However to help other understand easier, why not put some comment?

I have done that for you.

```
Sub ExtractData()

Dim selectedRange As Range ' Range to check
Dim Cell As Range
Dim iTotalRows As Integer ' Selected total number of rows
Dim i As Integer ' marker to identify which row to paste in new sheet

Dim shtNew As Worksheet
Dim shtData As Worksheet

Set shtData = Sheets("data")
Set shtNew = Sheets.Add()
shtNew.Name = "Analyzed data"

iTotalRows = shtData.UsedRange.Rows.count
Set selectedRange = shtData.Range("F2:F" & iTotalRows)

i = 1

' Check the selected column value one by one
For Each Cell In selectedRange.Cells

     If Cell.Value = "True" Then
        Cell.Copy shtNew.Range("A" & i)

        ' Copy the brand to column B in "Analyzed data" sheet
        shtNew.Range("B" & i).Value = _
                       shtData.Cells(Cell.Row, 2).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next ' Check next cell in selected range

End Sub
```