# Macro to copy Range to a new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How can I create a macro that would do the following:

1. Copy the range A2:AT10000 from one workbook to the first sheet of a new workbook.
2. Go back to the initial workbook and select range A6:HF10000 in the sheet with codename: Sheet11
3. Paste the selection to a newly added worksheet (sheet 2) of the workbook created in step 1

I get a run time error 424 and when debugging, the highlighted line is 
`Sheet11.Range("A6:HF10000").Select`

```
Sub Copy2RangesNewWorkbook()
'
' Copy2RangesNewWorkbook Macro
'
Dim pvt_wbk_New As Excel.Workbook
Dim pvt_xls_Current As Excel.Worksheet

With pvt_xls_Current
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:AT10000").Select
Selection.Copy
End With

Set pvt_wbk_New = Application.Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

With pvt_xls_Current
Sheet11.Range("A6:HF10000").Select
Selection.Copy
End With

With pvt_wbk_New
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Beware the differences between Worksheet.PasteSpecial and Range.PasteSpecial, as pointed out by Sid in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003620/paste-special-values-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Copy2RangesNewWorkbook()

Dim pvt_wb_New As Excel.Workbook
Dim pvt_ws_NewTarget1 As Worksheet
Dim pvt_ws_NewTarget2 As Worksheet
Dim pvt_ws_Current As Worksheet
Dim pvt_wb_Current As Workbook

Set pvt_ws_Current = ActiveSheet
Set pvt_wb_Current = ActiveWorkbook
Set pvt_wb_New = Application.Workbooks.Add
Set pvt_ws_NewTarget1 = pvt_wb_New.Sheets(1)
Set pvt_ws_NewTarget2 = pvt_wb_New.Worksheets.Add

pvt_ws_Current.Range("A2:AT10000").Copy
pvt_ws_NewTarget1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

pvt_wb_Current.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A6:HF10000").Copy
pvt_ws_NewTarget2.Range("A6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: One last thing though: 
In case I change the name of "Sheet 11" the macro would not work anymore. I would like to use the codename of the sheet, which is Sheet11.
    pvt_wb_Current.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A6:HF10000").Copy
I tried to change this line to: 
pvt_wb_Current.Sheet11.Range("A6:HF10000").Copy
But it is unsuccesful. I probably have to define it? Would be great if you could let me know, since the name of the sheet will definitely change by people other than me. Thanks